# bson document to jackson object node coversion

Tags: java, mongodb

So i'm trying convert bson document to objectNode using custom mongo converet, and getting error:
`org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: The uuidRepresentation has not been specified, so the UUID cannot be encoded`

My converter:

```
@ReadingConverter
public enum DocumentToObjectNodeConverter implements Converter<Document, ObjectNode> {
    INSTANCE;

    public ObjectNode convert(Document source) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            return mapper.readValue(source.toJson(), ObjectNode.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse DbObject to ObjectNode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Exceptions throws in source.toJson() method.

My bson doc:

```
'Document{{_id=0c79696c-f699-43fa-b126-d3efd47cdb42, code=weather-demo, createdAt=Fri May 28 10:48:33 ALMT 2021, updatedAt=Fri May 28 10:48:33 ALMT 2021}}'
```

What's wrong ?

I tried to add uuidRepresentation in my mongoTemplate and application.yml file:

My mongo config:

```
    @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings
                .builder()
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(mongoUri))
                .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)
                .build());
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, "test");
        MappingMongoConverter mmc = (MappingMongoConverter) mongoTemplate.getConverter();
        mmc.setCustomConversions(mainLib.mongoCustomConversions());
        mmc.afterPropertiesSet();
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
```

My application.yml:
`spring.data.monogdb.uuid-representation: standard`